# Angular add style tag into innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I create an Angular project and I wanted to insert `style` CSS into the html, but I don't want the inserted CSS replace other style that have the same tag or class name.

```
const testStyle = '<style>
  body {color: red}
  table {width : 200px}
  h1{font-size:12px}
  .another-same-class-name{color: blue;font-size: 13px}
</style>'
```

Above is my sample style that I want to insert into my component template

My Component

```
@Component({

   selector : 'app-my-component',
   templateUrl: './my-template.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./my-style.component.scss'],

})

export class MyComponent{

  myStyle:string

  ...

  ngOnInit(){
    const testStyle = '<style>
                         body {color: red}
                         table {width : 200px}
                         h1{font-size:12px}
                        .another-same-class-name{color: blue;font-size: 13px}
                      </style>'

    this.myStyle = testStyle

  }


  updateCss(newCss){
    this.myStyle = `<style>${newCss}</style>`
  }


}


<div #styleWillGoHere [innerHtml]="myStyle"></div>
```

Edit: I have update my question, to make it more clear :)

I appreciate any kind of solution.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is what's described in the documentation as [Component Styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

Comment: Does it work with static styles? Can you please add a stackblitz?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use DomSanitizer of `@angular/platform-browser` to sanitize the HTML.  
Take a look of the docs: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer.

In your particular case, you need to use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` method. Also, for apply styles only to one component, add an `id` to your target component and use it in your styles. (You can use class if that component will appear more than once in your web).

**EXAMPLE:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <div id="myId">
          <div [innerHtml]="myStyle"></div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  myStyle: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myStyle =
      this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<style>#myId h1{color: red}</style>`);
  }
}
```

**DEMO:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kza7c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your solution :), but this solution also change the color of `H1` on `HelloComponent`, when update style the `H1` on HelloComponent is NOT updating, only style at `AppComponent`. Thanks :)

Comment: @merahputih What you are looking for is pretty simple. Just put and id or a class to the parent component where you want to apply the styles. The isn't any magic for this, the style tag will apply the styles globally. I will update my answer to show you how.

Answer (score -1):

you can use DomSanitizer bypassSecurityTrustHtml

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35187606)